# Не выводит содержимое значения дальше первого пробела

Tags: post, php, mysql

почему в селекте значение из таблицы выглядит полным текстом с пробелами а при выводе  только до первого значения

```
$qwe =("SELECT * FROM  ведомость");
                $sq = mysql_query($qwe) or die(mysql_error());  
                $ro = mysql_fetch_array ($sq);
                echo  "<select name='disciplin'>"."<option >"."Название"."</option>";
                do   
                {

                echo "<option value=" .$ro['дисциплина'].">".$ro['дисциплина']."</option>";
                }
                while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($sq));
                echo "</select>";
```

тут нормально полный текст

а  тут только до первого пробела

```
$qr=$_POST["disciplin"];
echo $qr.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может так:

```
echo "<option value='{$ro['дисциплина']}'>{$ro['дисциплина']}</option>";
```

Comment: объясните научите! что это за магический способ!
пожалуйста!

Comment: вот очень интересно конечно вы как php учили? http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Comment: да не в сложном или простом синтаксисе строк проблема. А в вёрстке. Уважаемый @fiftyPoints просто не поставил ковычки у атрибута value

Comment: почему не нравится ему так то?=( почему такое извращение?... потому что нужно(


>echo '<option value='.{$ro['дисциплина'].', >'.$ro['группа']}.'>'.{$ro['дисциплина'].', >'.$ro['группа']}.'</option>';

>syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: Советую забить на этот формат и использовать нормальное объединение строк:

    echo '<option value="' .htmlspecialchars($ro['дисциплина']). '">' .htmlspecialchars($ro['дисциплина']). '</option>';

[htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) не даст попасть "кавычкам" вовнутрь атрибута `value`.

Comment: @научите
> почему не нравится ему так то?=(
Вы про сложный синтаксис прочитайте, это полезно. Ссылку вам выше дали.  
А не нравться ему, что фигурная скобка стоит без дела.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars()